# rearrange array to other side c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to shuffle array.

{10, 64, 79, 6, 13, -14, 1, 0, 66, 2}

It should do it when elements are smaller than 3 should be put on the left side and bigger than 3 on the right side

{-14 1, 0, 2, 10, 64, 79, 6, 13, 66}

```
int indexes[1000], c;

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    if(array[i] < 3)
    {
        indexes[c] = array[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on your expected output, it looks like you want to preserve the original relative order of the elements. You can use the [std::stable_partition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition) algorithm for that:

```
std::stable_partition(array, array + n, [](int i) { return i < 3; });
```

If you don't care about the relative order within a partition, you can just use `std::partition`.

Note that both these algorithms will also return the "partition point" which allows you to tell how many elements were moved to the beginning of the range.